# Autohotkey - Unable to read from webpage

Tags: internet-explorer, autohotkey

I have an issue with a small bit of code that is supposed to read the values of textboxes on a particular webpage. To test it I'm just using the search box for the google homepage. If I manually define the tab in Internet Explorer then it works fine, but if I try to programmatically define the tab using WinGetTitle it doesn't. I've checked and both instances ultimately use the string "Google" but only manually defining it works.

```
IEGet(Name="")
{
    For wb in ComObjCreate( "Shell.Application" ).Windows
        If ( wb.LocationName = Name ) && InStr( wb.FullName,     "iexplore.exe" )
        Return wb
}

WinGetTitle, Title, A
StringTrimRight, Title, Title, 20
wb := IEGet(%Title%)
testvar := wb.Document.All.q.Value
Msgbox, Value: |%testvar%|
```

If I change the IEGet to IEGet("Google") then it works. But leaving it as is above, despite "Title" being equal to "Google" it fails to find anything.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: After a bit of testing it seems the variable being passed into IEGet is getting lost somehow...

Comment: Ok so I just made the Title variable global and removed the need for "Name" inside the function. That seems to work. But now I've hit an issue with the website I'm trying to read from not returning a value, however I can't figure out if its something I need to change in the ahk script or the site is just stupid